# Creating multi-column Layout

Tags: html, css

I've been working with jQuery and HTML for a long while but don't have a ton of CSS experience.  I have been searching around and have found that with CSS you can make a lot better layouts than with the old school Table layout methods.

However, everything i've been finding appears to be a lot more work and sometimes doesn't seem to be as compatible.

I want to make a layout with a 
header/sidebar/ and main detail area.

Comment: You are not really asking a question. It would be good if you could rephrase your post so that it is in the form of a question, so that it can be properly and specifically answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to agree with you, creating a layout using CSS is very difficult.  However, there is a library similar to jQuery is to JavaScript call [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) that makes your goal extremely easy.  I highly recommend looking into it.

[Twitter Bootstrap - Scaffolding](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    Header
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">Side Bar</div>
    <div class="span10">Detail Area</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, in all my searches i didn't come across this library this seems easy to use and understand and from your example and the documentation i think i'll be good.  Thanks

Comment: If this answer is adequate to your needs, you should make it the Accepted Answer by clicking the check mark.